# Do I need to make changes to my manifest file for tablets?

Tags: android

I make one app and now I make my app for tablet. I want to know if  any change to the manifest file is necessary for my tablet app to be visible in tablets like Nexus 7 or any Samsung tablets.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.ibl.getbusinessdirection.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.ibl.getbusinessdirection.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.ibl.sharebizdeal.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.ibl.sharebizdeal.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Comment: Yes obvious. You must.

Comment: Do it using `supports-screens` manifest option. And BTW Tablets usually has no `Telephony` and even no GPS but according to your manifest you are using corresponding premissions. I'd rather remove such permissoins for a tablet targeting app.

Comment: Piyush... how to do that tell me???

Comment: Stan... oky but this app is for phone too.. tell me how to use `supports-screens`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visibility on device based upon screen size can be controlled by the below manifest tag

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
              android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
              android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
              android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
              android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Comment: Tahnx i got info for `supports-screens`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want the tablet app to have a different functionality than then phone equivalent, your don't need to change anything. A tablet is pretty much a bigger phone...it's all just a computer with Android OS running on it.

Edit:

Just realized this is a rather subjective answer, so if I have some false information here, correct me please^^

Comment: that's right but i just want to know that because i see many issue for tablet some friend make tablet app but not searchable in tablet

Comment: Sometimes apps wont be found in the play store search, because they dont have enough unique parts in their name and dont have enough downloads to get featured anyway. If you search for his name (the name he is using for publishing the app), the app will show anyway, as will all his apps.

Comment: Edit: I'm speaking from experience here. I made an app, and even if I search for the exact name, which is indeed unique on the play store, it wont show in the results, because its new and therefore doesnt have enough downloads to be featured.